# Adding onClick event to a footer in Jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, onclick, footer

I am trying to add an event to a jquery mobile footer. The source is like this below:

```
<div data-role="footer" id="footer">
    <h2>footer</h2>
</div>
```

So, when I touch the footer area on the phone, 
I want to show a website link.

How can this be done? I searched on google as usual but it didn't show what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: where should it show the link?

Comment: attach a click handler?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to attach a on click event listener to the footer div and then toggle the link display when the footer div has been clicked

```
<div data-role="footer" id="footer">
    <h2>footer</h2>
    <a href="www.google.com" id="link" style="display:none"> Some Link</a>
</div>

<script>
    $('#footer').click(function(){
        $('#link').show();
    });
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/na04dhet/

Comment: Thanks a lot, mplungjan.